# How can I know if RAM is compatible with my iMac?

Tags: imac, hardware, upgrade, memory

I want to buy a new iMac:
[Link](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/imac?product=MK462LL/A&step=config#)

And I need to upgrade the RAM. How do I know wich RAM is compatible with the iMac, for example:
[This RAM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008LTBJK2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Crucial website for all my Mac upgrades and never had a problem.

You can specify which model you want to upgrade and it will give you all the available (safe) upgrades.

In this case: [Link](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Apple/imac-%28retina-5k%2C-27-inch%2C-late-2015%29-imac17%2C1)

Alternatively you can navigate to the Apple logo on the upper left side of your mac and select *About this Mac*. Then select the *Memory* tab and check the specifications for the RAM modules.